# MessageComposer not displaying the body of the message in iOS8.0 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

This was, and is still working fine in iOS 7.1 (simulator and device). However after recently upgrading my Xcode to version 6, I tested the e-mail composition functionality and it no longer works. The body of the message does not show up. Here is some of the code pertaining to this functionality. I know similar questions have been brought up but none that matched my situation exactly.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ServiceViewController ()<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(void)showEmailView {
NSString *vehicleLog = [self getCoreVehicles];
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Vehicle Log"];

[self.shareImageData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    [picker addAttachmentData:[obj objectForKey:@"image"]  mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:[obj objectForKey:@"name"]];

}];

[picker setMessageBody:vehicleLog isHTML:YES];

picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
    self.selectedRecords = Nil;
}];

}
```

The error is:

2014-09-30 13:22:35.363 App[4919:356300] _serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error  Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceErrorDomain error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7aa37f20 {Canceled=service continuation}

If I tap on the area where the body should have been, the mail composer quits with an extra error.

2014-09-30 17:50:11.343 App[6055:429122]  timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService

I downloaded the sample code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MessageComposer/Listings/main_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161-main_m-DontLinkElementID_8 and same issue.

If anyone has faced something similar, or any tips, please let me know.

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing! Did you have any luck sorting this out?

Comment: Nope, still didn't get it to work.

Comment: Looks like it is an iOS 8 simulator bug. FWIW, it does work on device and on the iOS 7 simulator.